# Programming Calculations that replicates a Website

Tags: java, javascript, html

What I am trying to do is replicate a webpage into Java. The website I am using at this moment is [this](http://www.virginmobile.ca/en/plans/calculator.html).

I already have the exact layout, just need to get the calculations working, i have tried multiple times with different calculations but i keep getting an error. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the code for the layout so far:

Comment: Why would we do your work for you?

Comment: My guess is that the wbesite obtains the information from another database rather than calculate anything.  You need to be able to obtain this information from a simular database.

Comment: @AlexisPigeon I suspect he need to re-think his assumptions, doing the "work" is the least of his problems. ;)

Comment: *"just need to get the calculations working"*  Go for it!  Get back to us if and when you develop a specific *question.*  Voting to close as 'not a real question'.

Comment: Creating it with WindowsBuilder doesn't mean that you've done your work! @Peter Lawrey: It is a simple calculator

Answer (score 2):

Reverse engineer the website's JavaScript, and implement it in Java.

A good starting point will be this [script](http://www.virginmobile.ca/js/plans/data-calculator-combined.js).

And the data used for the calculations can be found in this [XML file](http://www.virginmobile.ca/en/catalogue/VMDataCalculator.xml).

Comment: +1 for actually providing an answer